# Weird Django TypeError: send_mail() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)

Tags: django, mail-server

I am trying to actually test sending an email using mailtrap.io, and I set up the email server as directed, however, when I try to do the following:

```
form = InterestedForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    subject = "Index form: Interested in Ucodon"
    message = 'Name: ' + name + '\n' + 'Email: ' + email
    recipients=['test@gmail.com']
    send_mail(subject, message, recipients, fail_silently=False)
    thanks = True
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: send_mail() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
```

I have even tried the following:

```
send_mail(subject=subject, message=message, recipients=recipients, fail_silently=False)
```

Also, I have defined EMAIL_HOST_USER. I am currently using EMAIL_HOST='mailtrap.io'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail):

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)¶
```

You are missing `from_email` argument.

Either set it, or pass `None` - in this case Django would use [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-from-email) setting value:

```
send_mail(subject, message, None, recipients, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: I thought that if you have a EMAIL_HOST_USER defined in ur settings, it will default to that as being the from_email?

Comment: @ngoctranfire nope, `from_email` should be passed in. `EMAIL_HOST_USER` would be used as `auth_user` argument value unless provided.

Comment: @ngoctranfire also see [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#quick-example).

Comment: Wow thanks! It worked, however, I seem to be getting another error that says the following: SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14... etc....'), with a link in there to my gmail, but this is extremely weird because none of the emails I have anywhere (from_email, or even the recipientlist) has any gmail information associated with it.

Comment: @ngoctranfire btw, you can also set `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` setting and it would be used in case you pass `None` inside the `from_email`. I've updated the answer and included that.

Answer (score 0):

Subject, message, from_email and recipient are required. I do not see you have provided the from_email. You can refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail for more info.